# Extra ext4 partition

Tags: partitioning, 22.04

when installing Ubuntu, I created an additional partition in ext4 format for my files (like drives in Windows), after installation, in order to be able to use it, I changed owner from root to my user with the chown command, So far there was no problem, I can use it easily
Now I have a problem and that is that standard users can't enter this partition at all, what should I do?

Comment: It is not clear what you want the standard users to do. Should they be able to read files only? Or read, write modify files? Delete files and folders? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1424168/edit) and elaborate what you want the standard used to do to your files and folders in that partition. Also add how do you mount that partition. If you have modified the file `/etc/fstab` add the contents of that file in your question.

Comment: @user68186 - Standard users cannot even read this partition

Comment: You are the owner. You have to decide what permissions y"our group" members and "others" should have with respect to this partition. that's what the `chmod` command is for. Alternately right click on the partition's folder and go to **Properties > Permissions Tab**.

Comment: @user68186 - In the permission, all the options are on read and write

Comment: Edit your question and add all the information.

Comment: @user68186 - My question is very clear, no user except me can enter the partition, when they click on the partition, it gives an access denied error and they can't even see the contents inside the partition.

Comment: @ArmInImrA What ownership and permissions does the top folder of that partition have? If you set it for example to `drwxrwx--- yourname yourname` then it's obvious that other users cannot access any contents in it.

Comment: @ArmInImrA Another possibility is that your user is in a group that is allowed to mount partitions via GUI and the other user isn't. Compare the ouput of `id -a` command run by both users.

Comment: This is a consequence of setting the ownership and permissions that you chose. Had you not done this, the volume would be accessible for other users. It's unclear why you can't or don't want to change it back to the way it was.

Comment: @raj - All the settings I made are as follows:
From  root:root  to sudo chown -R myuser:myuser , and 777 permissions